# how to upload directories on ftp server via php

Tags: php, file-upload, ftp

M a junior php developer, I am stucked in a problem that how to upload a whole directory containing several files and subfolders via php script to ftp server.. I have checked alot of method but none is working.. let I have a folder named "abc" and it contains many files and subfolders. I want to transfer it via php script using a loop which further searches for subfolders and files in subfolders of parent folder..
I used readdir() but it only geting sub directries..
Let me know the full step by step coding for that..
Thanks in advance...:)

Comment: So what are the methods you have checked and what was wrong with them, as there are many methods that do work and we would hate to waste your time by telling you to try all those methods that you have already tried.

Comment: Is it possible for you read the fordelr contents, create a directory with the same name and lopp the upload of every file?

Alternatively have you tried to zip via php, upload and then unzip?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
foreach (glob("/abc/*.*") as $filename)
   ftp_put($ftp_stream, basename($filename) , $filename, FTP_BINARY);
```

Hope this helps.